# Смена версии PHP на VDS

Tags: php, wordpress, vds

Прошу помощи в следующем вопросе:
Есть виртуальный выделенный сервер с установленным Debian 4.9. На сервере работает сайт на WordPress. Есть доступ по FTP, есть SSH. Панель управления - Vesta. ЦээМэС выдает предупреждение, что скоро для WooCommerce понадобится обновить версию PHP до 7.2 (сейчас установлена 7.0).
Техподдержка хостера такие услуги не оказывает, мол, мы вам предоставили сервер, дальше сами. И они тоже по-своему правы.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, толковый гайд, как это сделать. Руки не гнутые, но знаний не хватает.
И ещё, что с сервера мне нужно будет забэкапить, на случай, если что-то пойдёт не так?
Буду рад любой информации. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-php-7-2-on-debian-9/

Comment: Debian 4 был выпущен в 2010 году. Вы уверены?

Comment: @KAGG Design. Пардон, 9-я версия. Не туда посмотрел.

Comment: @Kirill Спасибо. Буду делать по инструкции, вроде всё понятно. А не подскажете, как и что мне залить в бекап. На всякий пожарный.

Comment: Как обычно - базу и файлы. Поставьте плагин BackWPUp и сделайте полный бэкап.